# Why is an iterable object not an iterator?

Tags: python, iterator

Here is my code:

```
from collections import deque

class linehistory:
    def __init__(self, lines, histlen=3):
        self.lines = lines
        self.history = deque(maxlen=histlen)

    def __iter__(self):
        for lineno, line in enumerate(self.lines,1):
            self.history.append((lineno, line))
            yield line

    def clear(self):
        self.history.clear()


f = open('somefile.txt')
lines = linehistory(f)
next(lines)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: 'linehistory' object is not an iterator
```

I have no idea why the `linehistory` object is not an iterator since it has already included `__iter__` method in `the` class.

Comment: You also need to define a `next()` method (or `__next__()` for Python 3).

Comment: `__next__` method missing: http://pymbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/igd.html#iterators

Comment: An `__iter__` method makes your object an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable), while a `__next__` method makes it an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterator). Use `lines = iter(linehistory(f))` and you'll be fine.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9884132/296974

Answer (score 34):

The concept of iteration is well documented [in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter).

In short, "iterable" is the object which provides the items I want to iterate over. Either it already cintains these items, then it is also called the container. This can be a list, a string, a tuple or anything else which consists of zero to many items.
But it also can be an object which produces items, for example one of the many classes contained in `itertools`. It has `__iter__()` which returns an iterator.

An "iterator" is the object which is used for one iteration. It can be seen as a kind of "cursor". It has `next()` (in Python 2) or `__next__()` (in Python 3) which is called repeatedly until it raises a `StopIteration` exception. As any iterator is iterable as well (being its own iterator), it also has `__iter__()` which returns itself.

You can get an iterator for any iterable with `iter(obj)`.

In your example, `linehistory` (which should be written `LineHistory`) is iterable as it has an `.__iter__()`. The generator object created with this is an iterator (as every generator object).

Answer (score 26):

Actually,

**All these other answers are wrong** (except for @glglgl who has an obtuse style of writing). Your generator function `__iter__()` would work as is if you called it with a `for` loop like so

```
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

But because you used `next(lines)` you have to first use `iter()` to get the iterator (I presume it just calls __iter__() on the object) like so

```
it = iter(lines)
print(next(it))
```

as [Mr.Beazley points out](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch04.html#_defining_generator_functions_with_extra_state)

Comment: "glglgl who has an obtuse style of writing" Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @glglgl You say the same thing twice and nether time does it bring clarity i.e. `"iterable" is the object I want to iterate over` and again `"iterator" is the object which is used for iteration`. You introduce `next` with explanation of what that is and do it again with generators. You basically assume the reader knows what: iteration, next(), and generators. But mainly you don't provide examples nor references to the introduced concepts.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added some more clarity (hopefully) and provided a link to help the reader find the "original" definition.

Comment: In my case (from your first example), `line` is a dict object. How can I extract just the keys from this (without looping through everything)?

Comment: @LShaver if you use a for loop on a `dict` you get just the keys. You can also use the `.keys()` on a `dict` and get a keys iterable which works like `lines`  in the above example

Answer (score 4):

> I have no idea why the linehistory object is not an iterator since it has already included `__iter__` method in the class.

Wrong. See [Iterator Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types):

> The iterator objects themselves are required to support the following two methods, which together form the iterator protocol:
>
> `iterator.__iter__()`
>   Return the iterator object itself. This is required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the for and in statements. This method corresponds to the tp_iter slot of the type structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.
>
> `iterator.__next__()`
>   Return the next item from the container. If there are no further items, raise the StopIteration exception. This method corresponds to the tp_iternext slot of the type structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.

However you can iterate over `lines`, that's because your `__iter__` method is a generator function, see [Generator Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types):

> Python’s generators provide a convenient way to implement the iterator protocol. If a container object’s `__iter__()` method is implemented as a generator, it will automatically return an iterator object (technically, a generator object) supplying the `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods. More information about generators can be found in the documentation for the yield expression.

Answer (score 1):

Iterator objects need an `__iter__` method but they also need to have `next` implemented:

> The iterator objects themselves are required to support the following two methods, which together form the iterator protocol:
>
> iterator.__iter__()
>   Return the iterator object itself.
>
> iterator.next()
>   Return the next item from the container.

[Python 2.7 Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)

In Python 3.x these are the function names:

> iterator.__iter__()
>
> iterator.__next__()

[Python 3.x Source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)

Answer (score 0):

Your object it is not an iterator the same way a list it is not an iterator, but an iterable. You could make it an iterator, though. Because an iterator is an object in its own.

```
help(list)
```

Then:

```
 |  __iter__(self, /)
 |      Implement iter(self).
```

Suppose you have a list:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

and you try to call

```
next(a)
```

You get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
```

But you can make an iterator of a list by applying an iter() on it.

```
>>> iter_a = iter(a)
>>> print(iter_a)
<list_iterator object at 0x03FE8FB0>

>>> next(iter_a)
1
```

So do this with your code:

```
f = open('somefile.txt')
lines = linehistory(f)
lines_iter = lines.__iter__()
print(next(lines_iter))
```

First line of somefile.txt (my file):

```
>>> %Run 'some file iterator.py'
aaaaaaa
```

Now do:

```
>>> dir(lines_iter)
```

You will see:

```
 '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__',
```

See? It now has a **next** method!

Answer (score 0):

**The Python "TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator" occurs when we try to use a list as an iterator. To solve the error, pass the list to the `iter()` function to get an iterator, e.g. `my_iterator = iter(my_list)`.**

Here is an example of how the error occurs.

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# ⛔️ TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
print(next(my_list))
```

We tried to use the list as an iterator, but lists are not iterators (they are iterable).

To solve the error, pass the list to the iter() function to get an iterator.

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

my_iterator = iter(my_list)

print(next(my_iterator)) # ️ "a"
print(next(my_iterator)) # ️ "b"
print(next(my_iterator)) # ️ "c"
```

The iter() function returns an iterator.

An iterator object represents a stream of data. Every time we pass the iterator to the next() function, the next item in the stream is returned.

When the iterator is exhausted, the StopIteration exception is raised.

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

my_iterator = iter(my_list)


try:
    print(next(my_iterator))  # ️ "a"
    print(next(my_iterator))  # ️ "b"
    print(next(my_iterator))  # ️ "c"
    print(next(my_iterator))
except StopIteration:
    # ️ this runs
    print('iterator is exhausted')
```

When you use a list in a for loop an iterator is create for you automatically.

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for el in my_list:
    print(el)  # ️ a, b, c
```

Iterators are required to have an **iter**() method that returns the iterator object itself.

Every iterator is also an iterable, however not every iterable is an iterator.

Examples of iterables include all sequence types (list, str, tuple) and some non-sequence types like dict, file objects and other objects that define an **iter**() or a **getitem**() method.

When an iterable is passed as an argument to the iter() function, it returns an iterator.
However, it is usually not necessary to use the iter() function because a for statement automatically does that for us.

When you use a for statement or pass an iterable to the iter() function, a new iterator is created each time.

On the other hand, you can only iterate over an iterator once before it is exhausted and appears as an empty container.
If you need to check if a value is iterable, use a try/except statement.

The iter() function raises a TypeError if the passed in value doesn't support the **iter**() method or the sequence protocol (the **getitem**() method).

If we pass a non-iterable object like an integer to the iter() function, the except block is run.

```
my_str = 'hello'
# my_str = 1  # raise exception

try:
    my_iterator = iter(my_str)

    for i in my_iterator:
        print(i)  # ️ h, e, l, l, o
except TypeError as te:
    print(te)
```

The iter() function raises a TypeError if the passed in value doesn't support the **iter**() method or the sequence protocol (the **getitem**() method).

If we pass a non-iterable object like an integer to the iter() function, the except block is run.

ref: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-typeerror-list-object-is-not-an-iterator