# TypeError: 'linehistory' object is not an iterator

Tags: python

when I learn  py cookbook ,there is a example tell me about that
TypeError: 'linehistory' object is not an iterator , but the linehistory have the **iter** method ???
well i don't understand it's meaning ,who can help me ???

```py
from collections import deque


class linehistory:
    def __init__(self, lines, histlen=3):
        self.lines = lines
        self.history = deque(maxlen=histlen)

    def __iter__(self):
        for lineno, line in enumerate(self.lines, 1):
            self.history.append((lineno, line))
            yield line

    def clear(self):
        self.history.clear()


def func():
    try:
        with open('somefile.txt') as f:
            lines = linehistory(f)
            for line in lines:
                print('{}'.format(line), end='')
            print()
            for lineno, hline in lines.history:
                print('{}:{}'.format(lineno, hline), end='')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
def func2():
    f=open('somefile.txt')
    lines=linehistory(f)
    next(lines)

func2()
```

Comment: here is the exact same question (so it is a duplicate) - and it has good answers: [Why is an iterable object not an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33956034/11470674)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This details a pretty similar issue:
[Why is an iterable object not an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956034/why-is-an-iterable-object-not-an-iterator)

The key point is that there is a difference between `Iterable` and an  `Iterator`.
[Iterables](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable)
[Iterators](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterator)

The upshot appears to be that to be an iterator your class also requires a next method. Alternatively you can get an iterator from your class using the `iter()` method which returns an iterator of an Iterable.

Answer (score 0):

The `linehistory` instance is an *iterable*, meaning that it can be iterated over, but it is not an iterator itself (it lacks the `__next__()` method).

To iterate over the lines, you need to obtain an iterator over the `linehistory` instance:

```py
lines_iter = iter(linehistory)
next(lines_iter)
```

Comment: I see that there already exists an answer to that, see the comments under your question (should be closed as a duplicate IMO).